# IEnumerable collection to List

Tags: c#, .net

I've written a CustomerCollection class, which implements the IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces. Now I want the CustomerCollection class object to be searchable by Where() And Find() function and also would like to get a List object of type Customer From the CustomerCollection class. Please help. Also, is the implementation of the interfaces right.

```
public class Customer
{
    private int _CustomerID;
    private string _CustomerName;

    public Customer(int customerID)
    {
        this._CustomerID = customerID;
    }

    public int CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            _CustomerID = value;
        }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomerName;
        }
        set
        {
            _CustomerName = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerController
{
    public ArrayList PopulateCustomer()
    {
        ArrayList Temp = new ArrayList();

        Customer _Customer1 = new Customer(1);
        Customer _Customer2 = new Customer(2);

        _Customer1.CustomerName = "Soham Dasgupta";
        _Customer2.CustomerName = "Bappa Sarkar";

        Temp.Add(_Customer1);
        Temp.Add(_Customer2);

        return Temp;
    }
}

public class CustomerCollection : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    ArrayList Customers = null;
    IEnumerator CustomerEnum = null;

    public CustomerCollection()
    {
        this.Customers = new CustomerController().PopulateCustomer();
        this.CustomerEnum = Customers.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void SortByName()
    {
        this.Reset();
    }

    public void SortByID()
    {
        this.Reset();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        CustomerEnum.Reset();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return CustomerEnum.MoveNext();
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return (Customer)CustomerEnum.Current;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your collection classes should never implement IEnumerable **and** IEnumerator (except for the rare case when there is only ever zero elements).  Enumerators are stateful and enumerables are not.  Your code won't work when GetEnumerator() is called more than once.

Comment: Do you mean `IEnumerable<T>`/`List<T>` or exactly `IEnumerable`/`List`?

Comment: why dont you just use List<Customer> and you get all the Where and Linq functions for free...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want. Note, I have abstracted out the IEnumerable to make it reusable and reduced the complexity of all of the other classes.

```
//Write your Test first
public class Test
{
    public void TestEnumerator()
    {
        var customers = new CustomerCollection();
        var qry = 
            from c in customers
            select c;

        foreach (var c in qry)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.CustomerName);
        }

        //Create a new list from the collection:
        var customerList = new List<Customer>(customers);
    }
}

public abstract class MyColl<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    protected T[] Items;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T item in Items)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Customer(int customerID)
    {
        CustomerID = customerID;
    }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerController
{
    public Customer[] PopulateCustomer() {
       return new [] {new Customer(1) {CustomerName = "Soham Dasgupta"},
                      new Customer(2) {CustomerName = "Bappa Sarkar"}};
    }
}

public class CustomerCollection : MyColl<Customer>
{

    public CustomerCollection()
    {
        Items = new CustomerController().PopulateCustomer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call `Cast<Customer>()` on your IEnumerable which will give you an `IEnumerable<Customer>`, or just implement `IEnumerable<Customer>` to begin with. LINQ is almost entirely hooked into `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`. Once you did that you'd get all the LINQ to objects goodness for free.

Comment: You should probably not cache your enumerator either, but instead return a new one with each call to `GetEnumerator`, each call to `GetEnumerator` should return an object capable of enumerating the collection without mucking with anything else. Having two enumerations share the same enumerator is problematic.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use `OfType<T>()` instead of `Cast<T>()` because if your collection contains T1 and T2, `collection.Cast<T1>()` will throw an error while `collection.OfType<T1>()` will return `IEnumerable<T1>` contains only instances of T1 not T2

Comment: Ah, but is it necessarily a bad thing to throw an exception when there's an unexpected element in there?

Comment: @Kirk: Depending on a case, of course. 99.99% of time where I use `OfType` is converting all this .NET 2.0 built-in, non-generic collections like ControlCollection, ElementCollection, so on, so on, to IEnumerable so I'm not sure what does they exactly contain so an addition check is ok

Comment: well, the name of his class is called "CustomerCollection" so it would seem startling (and worthy of an Exception) if it were to contain anything else. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomerController 
{ 
    public List<Customer> PopulateCustomer() 
    { 
        List<Customer> Temp = new ArrayList(); 

        Customer _Customer1 = new Customer(1); 
        Customer _Customer2 = new Customer(2); 

        _Customer1.CustomerName = "Soham Dasgupta"; 
        _Customer2.CustomerName = "Bappa Sarkar"; 

        Temp.Add(_Customer1); 
        Temp.Add(_Customer2); 

        return Temp; 
    } 
} 


public class CustomerCollection : List<Customer>
{  
    List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();  


    public CustomerCollection()  
    {  
        this.Customers = new CustomerController().PopulateCustomer();  
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new List<Customer>(myCustomerEnumerator);
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended base class to use for creating your own collection implementations is [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)

> *(from MSDN)*
>   This base class is provided to make it easier for implementers to create a custom collection. Implementers are encouraged to extend this base class instead of creating their own.

```
public class CustomerCollection : Collection<Customer>
{
}
```